# Image in rounded frame fails to conform to the frame on iOS but not Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I have some XAML in Xamarin Forms that creates a rounded frame containing an image.

```
        <Frame CornerRadius="45" HasShadow="false" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="5" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80" Margin="10">
            <Image Source="camerabutton.jpg" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" Scale="1.5">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                Command="{Binding CameraPageCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="camerabutton"
                                Tapped="OnCameraClicked"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </Frame>
```

I'm aware that there seem to be some issues regarding the frame element when it comes to iOS but I'm hoping someone can aid me with this issue.

On Android it works exactly as intended and perfectly cuts off the corners and displays a rounded cut out of the image. But on iOS the image merely overlaps, see images below.

[image] [image]

This is obviously not what I intended and my preference is to have it conform to how it looks on Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution  1 : 
First you try to set Property of frame `IsClippedToBounds="true"`

**OR**

Solution 2 :
Add rendering on IOS and here is the renderer code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Frame), typeof(CustomFrameRenderer))]
namespace YOU_IOS_NAMESPACE
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var view = (CustomFrame)Element;

        if (view != null)
        {
           Layer.CornerRadius = (nfloat)view.CornerRadius;
           Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        var view = (CustomFrame)Element;

        if (view != null)
        {
            Layer.CornerRadius = (nfloat)view.CornerRadius;
            Layer.MasksToBounds = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've already encountered this kind of bugs using Frame control. Perhaps you can try to use another control like this one: https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/RoundedBoxView

And why are you setting a padding of 5 on your frame?

Comment: Oh yeah. Forgot to remove that. I actually a frame in a frame to create a border. I removed the inner frame as it was unnecessary for the example code.